# want to scrape only text inside <ul> without spaces and balises

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using xpath, I want to scrape from this URL: https://www.le-dictionnaire.com/definition/tout'

I'm using this code but it brings spaces, new lines and balises li from the ul:

```
def parse(self, response):

    print("procesing:"+response.url)
    #Extract data using css selectors
    #product_name=response.css('.product::text').extract()
    #price_range=response.css('.value::text').extract()
    #Extract data using xpath
    title = response.xpath("//b/text()").extract()
    genre1 = response.xpath("(//span/text())[2]").extract()
    def1 = response.xpath("((//*[self::ul])[1])").extract()
    genre2 = response.xpath("(//span/text())[3]").extract()
    def2 = response.xpath("((//*[self::ul])[2])").extract()

    row_data=zip(title,genre1,def1,genre2,def2)

    #Making extracted data row wise
    for item in row_data:
        #create a dictionary to store the scraped info
        scraped_info = {
            #key:value
            'page':response.url,
            'title' : item[0], #item[0] means product in the list and so on, index tells what value to assign
            'genere1' : item[1],
            'def1' : item[2],
            'genere2' : item[3],
            'def2' : item[4],

        }

        #yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
        yield scraped_info
```

When I add the tag text()

```
def1 = response.xpath("((//*[self::ul])[1]/text())").extract()
def2 = response.xpath("((//*[self::ul])[2]/text())").extract()
```

it scrapes only blank spaces.

Comment: What's `response`? Can you give an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the text you want is not direct children of `<ul>` tag so using `/text()` would return direct children (or simply children) text. You need to get text from grand children of `<ul>` tag which is the text you want to scrape. For this purpose you can use `//text()` instead of `/text` or narrow down the XPath expression like:

```py
"//*[@class='defbox'][n]//ul/li/a/text()"
```

By doing this you have more clear list output also you can make a clean string of it:

```py
>>> def1 = response.xpath("//*[@class='defbox'][1]//ul/li/a/text()").getall()
>>> ' '.join(def1)
'Qui comprend l’intégrité, l’entièreté, la totalité d’une chose considérée par rapport au nombre, à l’étendue ou à l’intensité de l’énergie.\n\nS’emploie devant un nom précédé ou non d’un article, d’un dé
monstratif ou d’un possessif. S’emploie aussi devant un nom propre. S’emploie également devant ceci, cela, ce que, ce qui, ceux qui et celles qui. S’emploie aussi comme attribut après le verbe.'
```